# Switch from t-shell to bash and source file in one command line

Tags: bash, ssh

From my user on my machine, I ssh to a shared user on another machine that runs t-shell by default. I would like to create an alias that logs me in to the other machine as the shared user, `cd`s to my personal folder on that machine, switches shell to bash, and sources a script which defines some additional aliases. **How can I achieve this?**

This is what I've tried so far. From my machine I run:

```
ssh -ty <otheruser>@<otherhost> 'cd <myfolder>; source tsh.personal'
```

On the other machine, I have the file `~/<myfolder>/tsh.personal` which looks like

```
#!/bin/tsh
/bin/bash -c 'source ~/<myfolder>/bash.personal'
```

However, when I use the option `-c` for `bash`, it just runs the command and then exits, and then the connection to other machine closes because all comands passes to the `ssh` command has finished. I have also tried replacing the last row in `~/<myfolder>/tsh.personal` with

```
/bin/bash -c 'source ~/<myfolder>/bash.personal; /bin/bash'
```

which tells bash to start another instance of bash, which won't exit. However, when that instance is started, it is like `~/<myfolder>/bash.personal` was never sourced. Are all aliases reset whenever a new instance of bash is started, or why are the aliases not passed to the new instance?

Comment: I haven't used tcsh, but can't you just put "cd <myfolder>; exec bash" in the .tcshrc file? Then use normal bash startup init files like .bash_profile or .bashrc?

Comment: He can't directly edit `.bashrc`, since he's logging in as another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `tsh.personal` to

```
exec /bin/bash --rcfile ~/<myfolder>/bash.personal
```

The `exec` isn't strictly necessary, but it cleans up the process table by replacing the `tsh` instance with a `bash` instance.

Comment: According to the [bash map page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), the `--rcfile` option will execute commands from the given file *instead* of from the standard personal initialization file `~/.bashrc`. I want bash to execute commands from the given file as well as from `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I solved this by adding `source ~/.bashrc` to the top of my `bash.personal` file, even though I personally think that solution is a bit uggly.